# Azure Network Interface Effective Rules

Tags: network-interface, azure-nsg, network-security-groups

We are looking for an automated way to identify which are the ***Effective Security Rules*** that are applied to a ***Network Interface (NIC)***. We are aware that we can achieve this using a ***REST API call***: [Network Interfaces - List Effective Network Security Groups - REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaces/listeffectivenetworksecuritygroups)

But we have the following concerns about the output/result:

1. How many ***Network Security Groups (NSG)*** can be attached to a ***NIC***? Which is the current limit, or there is no limit at all?
2. When there are multiple ***NSGs*** attached to a ***NIC*** and those ***NSGs*** have different rules with the same priority how are they applied? How Azure make the merge of them?
3. Is there additional complexity added if a ***SubNet*** is also linked to them?

Answer (score 0):

You cant attach multiple NSGs to a NIC. You can attach one NSG to a NIC, also you can attach one NSG to the subnet.
If you attach NSG on both places, first the subnet NSG handles the traffic, then the NIC NSG.
More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-group-how-it-works